# htaccess redirect of php page to wordpress page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me to redirect my old url (http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programmedetails.php?pid=35&page=Child%20Care:%20Early%20Childhood%20Development) to new url (http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programs/early-childhood-development/) by htaccess. My old url is made on custom php framework and new url is on wordpress. I want to redirect my old url because it has many back links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=35&page=Child%20Care:%20Early%20Childhood%20Development$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^programmedetails\.php$ /programs/early-childhood-development/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Above code is fine but while I tried to redirect other pages like (http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programmedetails.php?pid=38&page=Volunteer%20Coordinator) to (http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programs/volunteer-coordinator/) page, it is not working. Similarily, this page (http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programfees.php?page=Program%20Fees) is also not redirect to this page ('http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/program-fees/')

Comment: If you show the rules attempted in your question then I can suggest a fix to make these rules work.